# Error: Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'int'

Tags: c#, operators, boolean-logic

I am newbie to C sharp programming and was writing the program to determine whether a number is power of 2 or not. But getting error as Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type int. Thought the same program works well in C++. Here is the code:

```
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int x;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number: ");

        x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        if((x != 0) && (!(x & (x - 1))))

            Console.WriteLine("The given number "+x+" is a power of 2");
    }
```

Comment: just remove the negation operator from this (!(x & (x - 1))) to this ((x & (x - 1))) it will work and present you with the desired result.

Answer (score 5):

In C#, the value `0` does not equal `false`, and `different than 0` does not equal `true`, which is the case in C++.

For example, this expression is valid in C++ but *not* C# : `while(1){}`. You must use `while(true)`.

---

The operation `x & (x - 1)` gives an `int` (int bitwise AND int) so it's not converted to boolean by default.

To convert it to a `bool`, you may add the `==` or `!=` operator to your expression.

So your program can be converted to this :

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    int x;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number: ");
    x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if((x != 0) && ((x & (x - 1)) == 0))
        Console.WriteLine("The given number "+x+" is a power of 2");
}
```

I used `== 0` to remove the `!`, but `!((x & (x - 1)) != 0)` would also be valid.

Comment: when I replace '!' with '-' it is working and changed the expression to bool type. It worked.

Comment: To invert all bits of an ordinal number, use the [`~`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d2bd4x66.aspx) operator.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen ~ is compiling but not working for the logic of the solution

Comment: But they do are equal tho, the language just doesn't accept that because it's supposed to be abstract.

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer by assigning boolean type to the expression and replace '!' with '-'

```
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
        int x;
        x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        bool y = ((x!=0) && -(x & (x-1))==0);
        if(y)
            Console.WriteLine("The given number is a power of 2");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("The given number is not a power of 2");
        Console.Read();
```